# Script to determine which shared libraries are not used?

Tags: linux, shell-script, utilities, shared-library

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I'm looking for a script that can run through and list out shared libraries that are not used.

The idea would be to `ldd` everything to create a list.  From there, for each shared library (that isn't a link), do a look up in the list to see if it exists (`grep`), if not, print it to the display as not in use.

Does such a script exist?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`binstats`](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/%7Eetzpc/binstats.html) will do this for you: its report includes a list of all unused dynamic libraries found in the dynamic linker’s search path.